# Oracle subquery invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I can not figure it out what is wrong with this query:

```
select * from inv_srv_inst inst, 
(select srvc.li_srv_cat_id from inv_li_srv_cat_srv srvc where srvc.srv_id = inst.service_id) li_srv_cat_id
where id in (37336558,37343286)
```

Error message:

> ORA-00904: "INST"."SERVICE_ID": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-00904: "INST"."SERVICE_ID": invalid identifier

You get this error because INV_SRV_INST is not in scope of the inline view. If you're using 12c or later you can work around this using the LATERAL keyword, which allows us to push predicates into subqueries:

```
select * 
from inv_srv_inst inst, 
lateral (select srvc.li_srv_cat_id 
         from inv_li_srv_cat_srv srvc 
         where srvc.srv_id = inst.service_id) li_srv_cat_id
where id in (37336558,37343286)
```

Although it must be asked, why did you choose an inline view rather than just joining the two tables?

```
select inst.* 
       ,srvc.li_srv_cat_id 
from inv_srv_inst inst
inner join  inv_li_srv_cat_srv srvc 
on srvc.srv_id = inst.service_id
where inst.id in (37336558,37343286)
```

Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a4590ade6c6e99141845db9476fef192).

Comment: I've solved this with join. But, sql server (dbms where I came from) supports this.

Comment: Yes, you'll find there are a few differences in SQL implementation between the two.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

In your case, you can express this using a lateral join or a correlated subquery -- assuming there is only one match.

```
select *
from inv_srv_inst inst cross join lateral
     (select srvc.li_srv_cat_id 
      from inv_li_srv_cat_srv srvc
      where srvc.srv_id = inst.service_id
     ) li_srv_cat_id
where inst.id in (37336558, 37343286);
```

Lateral joins are very handy.  They are like correlated subqueries but they can return multiple columns and multiple rows.